# Problema con php.ini

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo el siguiente problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trabajo con la version de php 5.3.3, segun este error, cuando me ocurrio por primera vez, lo unico que hice fue ampliar la variable grep memory_limit php.ini a 1024 M, ahora cuando mis aplicaciones tratan de subir un archivo, de 3.6 MB, me aparece el error que les muestro, por que pasa esto si la variable en realidad me soporta mucho mas peso de archivos?

Answer (score 0):

**Solución**

La solución que he encontrado, a sido aumentar el tamaño de la variable memory_limit en el archivo php.ini. de 128M la he aumentado de 512M, he reiniciado Apache y todo ha funcionado.

**Otra Solución**

El error informa de un límite de memoria de 1073741824 bytes, cambia el memory_limit en el archivo php.ini. de 128M a 2000M, entonces funcionara correctamente

Comment: Ya lo hice, como lo indico, actualmente en el php.ini lo tengo en memory_limit php.ini a 1024 M, el archivo que estoy subiendo es de 3.8 MB, deberia funcionar perfecto pero no se por que ahora no trabaja como se debe?

Comment: Por que razon si tengo 1GB, me aparece este error?